# How can I install MonoDevelop v4 on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, monodevelop

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I can install v2.8.6.3 of Monodevelop from software center but I need at least v3 to use Monogame v3 or higher. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Comment: Actually if you go to the [«installation» section](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives) of theMonoDevelop's site, you will see there an official PPA for Debian and derivatives.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Installing Mono develop 4 on 12.04 precise

#### Option 1: Compile Git version from source

First uninstall your current version of mono develop with the software centre then from the terminal run following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential automake checkinstall intltool git
sudo apt-get install mono-complete mono-addins-utils gtk-sharp2 gnome-sharp2
git clone git://github.com/mono/monodevelop
cd monodevelop
git checkout monodevelop-4.0
git submodule update --init --recursive
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```

#### Option 2: Installing from PPA

Un-install current version first

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:keks9n/monodevelop-latest
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install monodevelop-latest
```

From terminal run:

```
monodevelop
```

Comment: I gave up on monodevelop long ago but just saw your reply and decided to install anyway. I tried option1 and completed all steps succesfully but in the end I am unable to use monodevelop. There isn't any icon etc. to start it.

Comment: So going to the terminal and typing `monodevelop` pressing enter didn't start it up?

Comment: It did work, thanks. :) I didn't know you can start it just like that. Total newbie here.

Comment: The ppa you mentioned is outdated (at least the stable version).. The ppa linked in Salv0's answer is much better...

Comment: I'm getting an error compiling it from source: `Metadata file '/usr/local/lib/mono/monodoc/monodoc.dll' could not be found`

Answer (score 33):

The ppa from the first answer

```
ppa:keks9n/monodevelop-latest
```

seems to be outdated.

If you want to use the latest version ( 4.2.2+ ) with the latest runtime and so on, I suggest to use this new ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ermshiperete/monodevelop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install monodevelop-current
```

After this you will have monodevelop installed in the /opt/monodevelop.
To start the IDE use the following script:

```
/opt/monodevelop/bin/monodevelop-launcher.sh
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. 
To launch it, create a mono.desktop file with the following code: 

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Mono Develop
Exec='/opt/monodevelop/bin/monodevelop-launcher.sh'
Terminal=false

Comment: Careful with this: it doesn't add basic stuff like `mono` and `build` to the path, F# doesn't seem to build, F# binding is not yet supported under MonoDevelop 5.

Comment: s/build/xbuild.

Comment: Thanks, this made installation of a new workstation faster!

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source code from [here](http://monodevelop.com/Download) and compile it. I am using 13.04 and the version of mono is 3.0.3.2 on the software center.

You can try to download from the 13.04 center for your distro (from [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/monodevelop/))

Comment: I downloaded the source code but I can't compile it. I am stuck on step 2 [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo). I extracted the files to /usr/local/src and also got repositories from github but I don't know what to do with them.

Comment: I removed 2.8.6.3 and tried to download from the link you provided. I got 2.8.6.3 back.