# Cannot build MonoDevelop from source

Tags: gnome, compiling, gtk, mono

Whenever I try to install MonoDevelop it fails on the "./configure" command.

```
configure: error: Cannot enable GNOME platform without gnome-sharp-2.0
```

I have installed Mono 3.2 successfully into the `/usr/opt` directory. I have installed Gnome Sharp into the `/opt/gtk` directory.

When I go to my MonoDevelop directory (the place where the decompressed tarbal is) and execute `./configure --prefix="/opt/monodevelop` it exist with the error above.

I do in fact have the Gnome Sharp library installed. I got it from https://github.com/mono/gnome-sharp and it should thus be up-to-date.

I do want to note though, that the only files I can find inside the `/opt/gtk` seem to be gtk-related; and as Mono Develop says it did find GTK-Sharp but didn't find Gnome-Sharp, I'm assuming they are different things. I am 100% positive though I installed Gnome-Sharp and it was into the GTK directory.

I installed Gnome Sharp with the following command sequence:

```
./configure --prefix="/opt/gtk"
make
sudo make install
```

How do I make this work? I do not want to install anything through a package manager like apt or aptitude.

Comment: why dont you want to use apt? `sudo apt-get install mono-complete mono-addins-utils gtk-sharp2 gnome-sharp2` now build----done

Comment: @damien Because the distributions in the PPAs are outdated.

Comment: Both the git gnome sharp2 and ubuntu versions are both 2.24 so what is exactly outdated?

Comment: Also if worried about things being outdated why version 3.2 when version 4 is out? http://askubuntu.com/a/348504/71679

Comment: @damien I am installing 4.0... The PPA is stuck at 2.x.

Comment: @damien I think you are confusing MonoDevelop with Mono. I've Mono 3.2 and I'm trying to install MonoDevelop 4.0.

Comment: @JeroenBollen Could you resolve this?

Comment: @FloydPink No. I installed Arch instead and had the latest version straight from the default package servers.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same issue and after installing `gnome-sharp2` it got resolved