# MonoDevelop fails to compile VB (Vbc: pathToTool parameter cannot be null)

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to use MonoDevelop to compile Visual Basic in Ubuntu. I've installed MonoDevelop 4.2.2 as instructed in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348351/how-can-i-install-monodevelop-v4-on-12-04) from "ppa:ermshiperete/monodevelop". However I cannot build the sample Visual Basic project. With the following error:

```
/opt/monodevelop/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets: Error: Error executing task Vbc: Argument cannot be null.
```

Parameter name: pathToTool (Test)

I'm clearly missing some setup to build VB projects, any ideas how I can get them working?

I've tried:

- Reading the mentioned VB targets file doesn't show obviously where I should define a pathToTool parameter and I'm not exactly sure the Visual Basic tools it's referring to are even installed (though I don't know where to look.)
- Using a VM with Visual Studio. This works but it's annoying.
- Using a better programming language; colleges choice.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: same problem here - it's been two months, maybe some of you has figured it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use openSUSE 13.1 and installed MonoDevelop 5.0.1 from "Mono:Factory" repository.
These are the steps I used to solve the problem in my case:

**NOTE: You can jump to step 3 if you do not want to use the "*MSBuild build engine*" which is described in step 3.3**

1. Make a backup copy of "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" and then open it as root:

   sudo kate /usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets

   or

   sudo gedit /usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets
2. In section "vbc" change the last parameter "ToolPath" to the directory where vbnc is located:
3. Change some configuration of the "Project" in MonoDevelop if you face this error:

   error VBNC2017: The library 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll' could not be found.
4. In MonoDevelop go to menu "Project\YOURPROJECTNAME Options"
5. In "Build\General" set "Target framework" to "Mono / .net 4.0":

   Target framework: Mono / .net 4.0
6. - In "Build\Compiler" set "Additional compiler arguments" to "-libpath:YOUR-PATH-TO-MONO-4.0"

   Additional compiler arguments: -libpath:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/
7. In case you get the above mentioned error, again, go to "Build\General" and under the section "Build Engine" uncheck the "Use MSBuild build engine ..."